# (Selenium) Trying to locate Button with Span

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am trying to locate a Button with a span text. I already tried it with the class but the class is used 6 times.

HTML:

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-orange btn-border" ng-click="selectWorld(w.id)"> <span class="text world ng-binding">Krak des Chevaliers</span> </a>
```

C#:

```c#
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[span/text()='Krak des Chevaliers'])")).Click();
```

It can't find the Object. Please help :)

Comment: While I do not understand why your expression does not work, you could give a try to locate the `span` first and then get back to its parent element like this: `//a/span[text()='Krak des Chevaliers']/..`

Comment: It still won't work. I also tried xpath (absolute and relative) and it also didn't work.

Comment: What about this expression: `//*[text()='Krak des Chevaliers']/..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**
`By.xpath(“//*[contains(@class,’btn-orange’)` and

```
.//*[contains(.,’Krak des Chevaliers’)]]”)
```

It’s probably worth opening the page manually and experimenting by opening the dev tools, hitting `ctrl+F` and pasting your attempt. No point getting selenium to spin up and fire all the other steps while you’re having locator troubles - if you can find it in the dev tools with that XPath but not in the test then it might be an unrelated timing issue

Comment: Thanks :) I already installed Chrompath and copied the xpath from there.